# Use webprofiler to see entire query from view

Tags: 8, debugging

I am using Drupal 8. I have webprofiler enabled and am trying to see the entire query from a view since the query that shows on the view is not the complete view, its missing some fields. How do I use webprofiler to get this entire query?

Answer (score 0):

Check the saved profiles by the Webprofiler module via `/admin/reports/profiler/list`.

Go to the profile with the the same URL as your view and open it. Select the `Database` option on the left and search (CTRL+F) for the following string: `D\v\ViewExecutable::execute`.

You will find queries executed by the [ViewExecutable](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/class/ViewExecutable/8.4.x) class which is responsible for the data generation and query execution of your view.